# Trying to drain a string and map on its chars but failing because of type inference

Tags: rust, inference, collect

This code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=099357d062b383b26269460e12fa8a08&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn resolve_score(string: String) -> u16 {
    let mut score: u16;
    string
        .drain(..)
        .map(|char| {
            match char {
                'a' => score += 1,
                'f' => score += 4,
                _ => ()
            };
        })
        .collect();
}
```

generates this error:

```
<anon>:16:14: 16:21 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
<anon>:16             .collect();
                       ^~~~~~~
<anon>:16:14: 16:21 help: see the detailed explanation for E0282
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html?search=#method.fold) instead of [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html?search=#method.collect):

```
fn resolve_score(string: String) -> u16 {
    string.chars().fold(0, |mut score, char| {
        match char {
            'a' => score += 1,
            'f' => score += 4,
            _ => (),
        }
        score
    })
}
```

The `Iterator::collect` docs say:

> Transforms an iterator into a collection.

and `Iterator::fold`:

> An iterator adaptor that applies a function, producing a single, final value.

In your code you are interested in producing a single final value (`score`), not a collection, so `fold` is more appropriate.

*Observation*: your function takes the ownership of the string, so using `drain` makes no difference because the string will be dropped anyway (thanks for the comment [Matthieu M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m)). If your intention is to consume the string, making it empty, but not take the ownership, you can declare the function like this:

```
fn resolve_score(string: &mut String) -> u16
```

and use `drain`, so the string will be empty after the function returns. If the string does not need to be consumed, you can receive a `&str` parameter:

```
fn resolve_score(string: &str) -> u16
```

---

Also note that `collect` failed because it was not possible to infer which collection to produce. You could have written:

```
fn resolve_score(string: String) -> u16 {
    let mut score: u16 = 0;
    string.chars()
        .map(|char| {
            match char {
                'a' => score += 1,
                'f' => score += 4,
                _ => (),
            };
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    score
}
```

but this would be weird because you would not use the resulting collection (of empty values).

Comment: Good suggestion with fold - first I wasnt sure if I should use map or fold...but fold is actually the best solution for this because of the aggregator...stupid me :(

Comment: @xetra11: if you do not use the result of `collect`, then you should look for another way to consume the iterator. `for char in string` is another possibility, and quite more lightweight than this `drain` + `map` + `collect`

Comment: I would note that `drain` is useless here, and mutating the `String` is useless too. `fn resolve_score(string: &str) -> u16` is quite sufficient.